# Execute PowerShell script from php

Tags: php, powershell

I want to execute a PowerShell script using php. Using cmd it is working fine, but it is not working using php and I am using wamp server.

My code is as follows:

```
<?php
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
//$output=shell_exec('cd C:\AWS\Distributed-setup-3');
//$output=shell_exec('cd');
$output=shell_exec('powershell.exe -command C:\AWS\Distributed-setup-3\AWSExecuter.ps1');
echo $output;
?>
```

Here I am using `Input.yaml` file for taking inputs it is giving error as, Problem in Input file 'Input.yaml'. But for manual execution I am using same input file. There it will not give any error.

Can anyone help me? Since three days I am working on this. I am getting how to debug this one.

Comment: Please provide the contents of Input.yaml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was problem with python code which I was calling in powershell script, I have solved it.Now it is working fine.

In php I have used like this,

```
<?php
        ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
        $output= shell_exec('powershell -command C:/AWS/Distributed-setup-3/AWSExecuter.ps1');
        echo( '<pre>' );
        echo( $output );
        echo( '</pre>' );          
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change $psDIR to your PowerShell path (e.g. %SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v2.0)

```
<?php
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
$psPath = "powershell.exe";
$psDIR = "PathToPowrshell";
$psScript = "C:\AWS\Distributed-setup-3\AWSExecuter.ps1";
$runScript = $psDIR. $psScript;
$runCMD = $psPath." ".$runScript;
$output= shell_exec($runCMD);
echo( '<pre>' );
echo( $output );
echo( '</pre>' );
?>
```

Comment: I have tried this one it is not giving any output or any error.II have mentioned  like this in $psDIR %SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0.

Comment: Can you change %SYSTEMROOT% like this  `$psDIR = "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0";`

Comment: It was problem with AWS python code, I have solved it.Now it is working fine. In php I have used like this,<?php
  ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
        $output= shell_exec('powershell -command C:/AWS/Distributed-setup-3/AWSExecuter.ps1');
  echo( '<pre>' );
  echo( $output );
  echo( '</pre>' );          
 ?>

Comment: That's nice to hear mate. Happy coding!